# Install Windows 8.1 on Windows 8 Pro with Media center addon key

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

This question has been asked earler in this forum but a clear answer for the same is not yet available for the people who bought windows 8 pro upgrade

I purchased **Windows 8 pro upgrade** from Win 7 ($40 Win upgrade offer) also I got a free **Windows Media Center Addon Pack key**....

Currently Mys system is :

**Windows 8 Pro with Media Center**

After reading other questions i found that to install Windows 8.1 standalone i have 2 options

- Windows Store
- MSDN/Torrent iso download and use a defualt key to install

So i have with me :

- Windows 8 Pro Key
- Media Center Addon Key
- Torrent to [Untouched ISO (All In One)](http://thepiratebay.sx/torrent/8963782/Windows_8.1_AIO_x64_en-US_ESD_Baseline)

**I still have some questions :**

- Is Upgrade Possible as standalone or Store is the Only way for me??
- Which OS to choose for upgrade from the ISO: Win 8.1 Pro or Win 8.1 Pro WMC ??
- IF i Choose ProWMC how will i activate it as i have Only Pro Key with Addon Pack key of WMC
- If I choose Pro will the addon pack key will work (although i never use it)

It would be really helpful if someone could guide me on this...
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post a link of the other question?

Comment: @adcool2007 See my answer to this question it maybe of assistance http://superuser.com/questions/661261/windows-8-1-fresh-install-with-windows-8-licence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro and then use the WMC key after installation in the Add Features section.

The WMC keys you received last year work this year too.

Source: Personal experience

Comment: What about Install source in the MSDN ISO/Torrent Link is good for it ??

Comment: If that ISO is untouched, it is fine. Generally, they're tampered with for piracy. So, make a wise decision

Answer (score 2):

Copy the DVD (cotent from monted ISO) to your HDD, mount the install.wim and convert the SKU into Media Center:

```
Dism /Image:C:\Mount /Set-Edition:ProfessionalWMC
```

unmount the WIM and now you have a good Image. Run the Setup.exe and select "upgrade".