# Windows 8 placeholder keys

Tags: windows-8, installation, product-key

As noted here

[Windows 8.1 fresh install with Windows 8 licence](https://superuser.com/q/661261/#661276)

Windows 8.1 has available "generic keys" that will let you install Windows 8.1,
but not activate. Does Windows 8 have similar keys, that let you install but not activate?

Comment: Yes.  These keys do indeed exist.  `46V6N-VCBYR-KT9KT-6Y4YF-QGJYH` for Windows 8 and `V7C3N-3W6CM-PDKR2-KW8DQ-RJMRD` for Windows 8.0 Profesional

Comment: @StevenPenny - The source is my own research 8 months ago.  I just created a text file which contains the the information if I ever required it.  Although the keys are different I found [this](http://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/a-clean-install-of-windows/microsoft-product-activation/installation-of-windows-8-1-with-a-windows-8-0-retail-product-key-notes/) which lists same 8.1 keys I have archived.  Although the keys are "different" their keys are also untested (unlike mine)

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger those dont work with the retail version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Retail

Windows 8

```
FB4WR-32NVD-4RW79-XQFWH-CYQG3
```

Retail Windows 8 Professional

```
XKY4K-2NRWR-8F6P2-448RF-CRYQH
```

[Source](http://heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/70-windows-8-direct-download-links)

## OEM

Windows 8

```
46V6N-VCBYR-KT9KT-6Y4YF-QGJYH
```

OEM Windows 8 Professional

```
V7C3N-3W6CM-PDKR2-KW8DQ-RJMRD
```

[Source](http://microsoft.com/oem/en/installation/downloads/Pages/Windows-8-ADK.aspx)

Comment: The keys I provided are not OEM generic keys

Comment: @StevenPenny - I have used them personally and went on to use both System Builder and Upgrade licenses both on physical and virtual machines.