# Boot Camp temporary serial Windows *

Tags: windows-8

My Macbook Pro is late 2011. Have done all usual, edited Boot Camp plist. Still issues with Win7 so figured try Win8. Downloaded iso En only from MS. Install starts great and gets as far as Windows setup but asking for product key and no way to bypass. I do not have a 8 product key. This is intermediary step as once installed have genuine Win10 product key and will simply upgrade and activate. But stuck on Win8 install. Tried using some generic keys but no luck. How can I get a temporary key to bypass and continue install? Once up and running I can then upgrade.

Follow on question. Best way to upgrade to 10?

Comment: Why are you trying to install Windows 8 and then upgrade to Windows 10? Just install Windows 10. Download and create the installation media with the Windows Media Creation Tool. What you are looking for is a generic key. Just google for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8 placeholder keys](https://superuser.com/questions/749414/windows-8-placeholder-keys)

Comment: @Appleoddity - That MBP doesn't support Win10 out of the box. You probably have to cheat & install 7 or 8, then upgrade. [I have  no citation & have never tried it myself, my own BC started life as WinXP & has been upgraded right the way through over the years]

Comment: Tried again with Win10 and got as far as having to reformat volume during install. Have done the necessary cheating!