# How to upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 offline?

Tags: windows-8.1

How do I upgrade a Windows 8 machine without a network connection to Windows 8.1?

Comment: You should be able to use http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271128 and the key contained in the accepted answer to this questionr: http://superuser.com/questions/661261/windows-8-1-fresh- install-with-windows-8-licence in order to do this. After your upgrade is finished you will have to change the license back to your Windows 8 installation described by the accepted answer here http://superuser.com/questions/650019/how-to-use-windows-8-1-rtm-with-8-0-key/650055#650055 **When I can provide an answer that isn't all links I will post an answer.**

Comment: I don't think any of you have noticed that using the ISO, we lose all non-metro-applications. It's just as if we did a refresh: we have to reinstall all non-metro-apps afterwards. Yes, I tried it, only metro-apps survive this type of upgrade. There is no way shown to upgrade it offline and achieve the same as with the online upgrade. While on my first 2 win8 pro it did not work (as described before), on the other 4 it worked. A little irritating, yes. All actions were the same. So I assume, the upgrade procedure is not 100% stable.

Comment: @hagen I used the ISO did an in-place upgrade without a problem

Answer (score 2):

Download a Windows 8.1 ISO (when you have access to it via MSDN/Technet), mount it inside Windows, run the `setup.exe` and select "upgrade".

Comment: What would I put for the serial number?

Comment: @Mehrdad - I already answered this question through a comment.

Comment: Issue with this to be aware of that MSDN/technet is not meant for production. MSDN is for development & TechNet is for testing. So if you have a retail key, it isn't the supported methods for this.

Comment: MSDN/Technet is the only way to get clean ISOs.

Answer (score 0):

[A MVP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1448f8bc-78a0-4264-ace1-fb152d9ab87e/offline-upgrade-from-windows-8-to-windows-81?forum=w8itproinstall) suggest you to use [this](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57608376-285/how-to-download-the-official-microsoft-windows-8.1-iso) third-party solution.