# Windows 8.1 Upgrade fails with error code 0x80070652

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have a Thinkpad T530 running Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 from a MBR-partitioned disk, with GRUB being the installed boot loader. I can see that the Windows 8.1 upgrade is offered to me in the Market, but I receive the **0x80070652** error code when I try to install the upgrade. It downloads fine, but fails during preparation.

More (may be too much) details about my setup:

- I initially upgraded to Windows 8 Pro with Media Center 64-Bit via upgrade offer from Windows 7 64-Bit without keeping any data.
- Latest Intel graphics drivers from Windows Update are already installed. My laptop has only integrated Intel graphics, no AMD or Nvidia.
- I have 4 partitions on the drive, with all of them being primary partitions.

  - The table looks like this: Ubuntu LTS Swap, Ubuntu LTS root filesystem, Ubuntu LTS `/home` partition, Windows 8.
- I also have a GPT-partitioned mSATA SSD running the latest Ubuntu non-LTS-release, but I removed that to do the upgrade.

As I said, I already tried removing the GPT partitioned SSD and tried only booting legacy/MBR style, leaving me with error code 0x80070652 during (attempt to install/prepare) the Windows 8.1 upgrade.

I also tried:

- Looking up the error code. I remember reading a knowledge base article that suggested moving/deleting the contents of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. I did that, but no luck.
- Executed "Disk Cleanup" as well as "Clean up system files".
- Freed up more than **30 GiB** of available diskspace on the Windows partition.
- Disabled swap file and hibernation and also deleting the corresponding files. Not luck, enabled them again.
- Runnning `WindowsUpgradeAssistant.exe` and removing all incompatible applications (it gave me only 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I read that one needs more than 30 GiB of available diskspace](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/81-install-error-0xc1900101-0x40019-and-0x80070652/2ed22001-a064-4925-ba14-3096ebabab4e?page=4) and incrementally freed up 5 GB to try again until it continued at around 45 GB of free diskspace.

I then received error code 0x80070002 in my case and [was able to fix that](https://superuser.com/questions/661890/windows-8-1-install-error-0x80070002/662585#662585). The upgrade went through without any further issues.