# Windows 8.1 not downloading from store

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-store

I clicked on "Update to Windows 8.1 for free" from the Windows 8 Store, and I've been waiting for 2 hours, and the download bar is still not filling up.

Why would this happen? Is there is an update I haven't downloaded?

Comment: Unfortunately there are way too many possible reasons "why" based on the information provided for us to answer.  Did you try rebooting once and restarting the download?  Did you try clearing your store caches?  Is there anything related to the problem in your Event Logs?

Comment: @techie007 I've tried all that. Could you tell me more about the Event Logs? That sounds unfamiliar.

Comment: @techie007 It now gave me an error code of 0x80070652 in the install. What does this mean?

Comment: I was able to find a solution by doing a google search http://superuser.com/questions/680097/windows-8-1-upgrade-fails-with-error-code-0x80070652