# Using student disk to upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I live in New Zealand, where most peoples internet is terrible. In order for me to upgrade all of my computers to Windows 8.1 I would need to download 11.5GB of files, the same files mind you.

However, I am a university student and as such have access to Microsoft Dreamspark. I downloaded the ISO from Dreamspark prior to the official release. My computers all use legitimately purchased Keys (not my student key) with Media Center enabled. I tried to upgrade to Windows 8.1 via the student ISO, but got a message stating that "The key doesn't work with this version of windows". What is the best option here?

Also, why is the update so big, it seems to be the same size of the FULL Windows 8 ISO. Seeing as most will only ever update via the Windows Store, it makes more sense to me to just include an incremental update. Is there a deeper problem here?

Comment: The update is so big because it changes a ton of stuff.  The best way is to use the generic key with the correct version of the Windows 8.1 iso either Professional or Core then change the activation key to your normal Professional key then use the media center key to "upgrade" after you reactivate your key or just follow this answer http://superuser.com/questions/650019/how-to-use-windows-8-1-rtm-with-8-0-key/650055#650055 Windows 8.1 isn't an incremental update.

Comment: 8.1 is a FULL NEW Windows, MS only named it update instead of upgrade to save money: http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-calls-windows-81-an-update-not-a-upgrade-for-the-money Yes you can use the Dreamspark ISO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows 8, get the update from the Microsoft Store tile. Windows 8.1 update size is 3.63GB. 
If you have earlier versions of Windows, back up important files and do a fresh install from your Dreamspark ISO.

That is your safest bet.
With Windows 8.1, Microsoft deprecated WET (Windows Easy Transfer) and backup/restore compatibility with earlier windows versions is unclear.