# Resetting a Windows 8.1 machine with only a Windows 8 product key

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm trying to completely wipe my PC of all personal data and install Windows 8 or 8.1.

I purchased Windows 8 and then upgraded it to 8.1.

Following [these](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) instructions I went to PC Settings -> Update and Recovery -> Recovery -> Remove everything and install Windows. I get prompted for an installation disc. According to [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) it's not possible to create 8.1 installation media with only a Windows 8 product key. So I created a Windows 8 disc. It doesn't work. I get prompted that some files are missing and to insert media.

How can I most easily get back to a completely new installation (that wipes all my old files)? Either 8 or 8.1 is fine.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Windows 8.1 generic key instead? I talk about how that is possible in this question. http://superuser.com/questions/650019/how-to-use-windows-8-1-rtm-with-8-0-key/650055#650055 If this is an OEM machine you can also use the OEM restoration image.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks. It's not an OEM machine.

Comment: Reset is also an option in that case