# Windows 8.1 update link in Windows store not working

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, updates, windows-store, windows-store-app

I am attempting to update an HP 2000 series laptop from Windows 8 to 8.1.

I performed a factory reset on the laptop then proceeded to install windows updates. After the windows updates were installed the Windows store would not load. This was resolved however the 8.1 update link in the store was unresponsive.

Is there a way to update without going through the store while not having the product key or to fix the link?

Answer (score -1):

The only update available to go from Windows 8.0 to Windows 8.1 is to use the Microsoft Store. As an IT Tech it is a proper PITA that we do not have access to a standalone download to allow us to get this major update done.  In some cases it has taken 10+ goes to get the 8.1 update installed from the store which wasted many gigabytes of downloading/time.

Do checkout this page in case it can help your Store Link issue.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You can use a Windows 8.1 ISO of the exact same version, use a generic key, then activate with your OEM license.  I already published an answer that goes into detail how that works.  Additionally we expect more out of answer than a link, quote the relevant information.  I have performed this operation over a dozen times

Comment: For an end-user, where do they get a 'generic key' from and how can you activate Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8.0 key (they are not the same). Having tried this without success, for an end user I stand by my answer at this stage. I do not see the need to quote a webpage from microsoft which is described in its link what it is going to do.

Comment: I have already published an answer that goes into detail about generic Windows 8.1 license keys and how to activate Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8.0 installation.  You do understand Windows 8.1 can be actiavted with a Windows 8.0 license right because it's a few upgrade right?  If not do some research the. You will understand the reason this answer is incorrect

Comment: Don't feel like returning so here is my previous answer  http://superuser.com/questions/650019/how-to-use-windows-8-1-rtm-with-8-0-key/650055#650055