# Installing Windows 8.1 using Windows 8 DVD

Tags: windows-8, installation, upgrade, anti-virus

I need to install Windows 8.1 but unfortunately lack an installation medium. I have a Windows 8 DVD and could install Windows 8 first, then upgrade from Windows Store. But I am not sure what is the right way?

1. Option 1: first install all updates, upgrade to Windows 8.1 and after that install antivirus software.
2. Option 2: first install antivirus software (involving browsing for software in the internet with outdated Windows 8) and after that do all the Windows updates and finally upgrade to 8.1

During that time I am not using the PC actively I will only connect to Internet to use Windows Update and Windows Store for upgrade to Windows 8.1 (No surfing in the internet, no data transfer via USB etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to install Windows 8.1 but unfortunately lack an installation medium. I have a Windows 8 DVD and could install Windows 8 first, then upgrade from Windows Store. But I am not sure what is the right way?

It seems like it would be easier to just download a Windows 8.1 ISO and install it.  The best method, will entirely depend, if the license is for `Windows 8` or `Windows 8.1`.

[It is possible to install Windows 8.1 with a generic key and activate it with your Windows 8 key.](https://superuser.com/questions/650019/how-to-use-windows-8-1-rtm-with-8-0-key/650055#650055)  However, it is not possible to install Windows 8, with your Windows 8.1 key.

> Option 1: first install all updates, upgrade to Windows 8.1 and after that install antivirus software.

If creating a `Windows 8.1 Update 1` ISO is out of the question.  I suspect this is the "best" method given the two options you have described.  Worth pointing out there is virtually no difference between the two options.

However, I also suspect, you will encounter problems performing the upgrade to `Windows 8.1`.  `Windows 8` is not currently supported, so I suspect you will be unable to perform the upgrade to `Windows 8.1` through the Windows Store, this upgrade is of course required in order to install `Windows 8.1 Update 1` which is the only supported version of `Windows 8.1`

I documented an easy accessible process to download a `Windows 8.1` ISO in one of my previous answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by installing Windows 8, *using the built-in Windows Defender as antivirus/antimalware*, install any updates you need before upgrading to Windows 8.1, upgrade to Windows 8.1, and then installing whatever your preferred antivirus/antimalware is. I would also give serious thought to upgrading to Windows 10.